# Absolute value of power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let M be a set with |M| = n element in N. Show with complete induction that the number of all subsets with uneven absolute value from M is $2^{n-1}$.

My beginning of the induction is |M| = 1 with M = {m1} so the subsets are {m1} and the null-set and {m1} is the only subset with uneven absolute value. I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Note: the term is "cardinality," not "absolute value," even though they use the same symbols.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to prove the size is $2^{n-1}$ for both even and uneven subsets simultaneously.  You have the base case OK.  For the induction: Let $|M|$ = $n+1$, fix some $m_k$ in $M$, and partition the subsets of $M$ into those containing $m_k$ and those not containing $m_k$.  The size of $M$\{$m_k$} being $n$, there are $2^{n-1}$ even, and $2^{n-1}$ uneven, subsets not containing $m_k$.  NOW: What can you say about sets containing $m_k$?

Answer (score 1):

I think that answer with induction on sets cardinality and asking about behavior without given element is the best solution, but if you want you can do it directly from the Newton's symbol propetries.

---

$$ 1 $$
$$ 1\ 1 $$
$$ 1\ 2\ 1 $$
$$ 1\ 3\ 3\ 1 $$
$$ 1\ 4\ 6\ 4\ 1 $$

Let's look at the Pascal's Triangle. Every row represents cardinality of the set that the subets of you're interested in. Each element of the row says about the number of the subsets with given cardinality.
e.g. 1 3 3 1 is the row corresponding to the set with cardinality 3, and

- 1 - number of subsets of cardinality 0
- 3 - number of subsets of cardinality 1
- 3 - number of subsets of cardinality 2
- 1 - number of subsets of cardinality 3

so we can ask this question by just summing right elements:
if n is odd, then the row is symmetrical and we can just write correspondence: 
$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$, and just pair the elements and say the sum is equal.
If number is even though - we can say that the sum of even (or odd) numbers is equal to the sum of all numbers from the higher row. That is because for numbers on even "indexes" of the row (in row 1 4 6 4 1 that would be 4 4) you can easily see what parts of the higher row (1 + 3 and 3 + 1) summed up to them (we use the fact that $\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$ (pascal triangle property), and for odd indexes we see the same thing for indexes other than 1 and n, which leave 2 ( 1 from the left and 1 from the right side) remaining to the sum, which are just added on the indexes 1 and n. Therefore we have equality.